# How to go from Python numpy 3D array to 2D to 1D back to 2D (preserving the original 2nd and 3rd dimension of the 3D array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have an 3D array, a:

```
`print(a.shape)
In [1]:(4, 4571, 8893)
b = a.reshape(a.shape[2]*a.shape[1],a.shape[0]) # Here I've also tried changing the shape of with (a.shape[2]*a.shape[1],a.shape[0])
print(b.shape)
In [2]:(40649903, 4)
c=some_function(b) # returns c which has same shape as b.shape[0]
print(c.shape)
In [2]: (40649903,)
d = c.reshape(a.shape[1],a.shape[2]) # same shape as a.shape[1:]
print(d.shape)
In [3]:(4571, 8893)
```

`

Now when I look at d, I get a shape like this:

```
plt.imshow(d)
```

[image]

But it has to be like the image shown below (pl. ignore the color, the shape of the yellow region has to be like the navy blue region):

```
plt.imshow(a[0])
```

[image]

Perhaps this is related to axis of reshape, but I am not able to figure where I'm using the wrong axis to reshape. I've given some thought to this, and read the numpy documentation, but the documentation and online examples (SO questions) don't seem to have a clean example for my specific problem. Any directions of what I'm missing would help.

Comment: Experiment with something small, like np.arange(24.reshape(4,3,2).  reshape to (4,6) is quite different from reshape to (6,4).

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! I didn't think of that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer for others who might have the same issue:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
print(a); print(a.shape)

b = a.reshape(a.shape[0],a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]).T; 
print(b); print(b.shape) # X

c = a[0].flatten() # Y
print(c); print(c.shape)

d = c.reshape(a[1].shape); 
print(d); print(d.shape) # same as print(a[0].shape)
```

Thanks for your advice @hpaulj